# How to find count(*) using JDBC in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to find the count of the occurence of a name in a mysql table using the query:

`select count(*) from employeedetails`

How do I fetch the result to a java integer variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ResultSet#getInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(int)) to return the integer value of a queried column by its ordinal place (i.e., first column is 1, second column is 2, etc):

```
try (Connection con = /* connect to the database */;
     Statement s = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select count(*) from employeedetails") {

     // This query returns at most only one row
     if (rs.next()) {
         int numEmployees = rs.getInt(1);
         // Do something with numEmployees
     }
}
```

Comment: Well done. Someone's homework done

Comment: You forgot `rs.next()`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel true 'dat, shame on me. Edited and fixed.